# Google Cloud MySQL Instance Access Control possible via Firebase Anonymous Authentication?

Tags: mysql, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I am currently building a price comparison serverless web application on **Firebase Hosting** with more than 300K products (documents) in a **Firestore DB**.

**Firestore** has still some **limitation** when it comes to **filtering** (see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations)) so im trying to find an alternative to Firestore DB that includes some sort of **authentication**.

Note: being able to filter for multiple keys (e.g. all blue cars sorted by ranking index and cheaper than 25K is currently not possible in Firestore) is more important than scalability

Question: is it possible to use the [Firebase Anonymous Authentication method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth) to limit access to a [Google MySQL Instance](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/instance-access-control)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud SQL is not integrated with Firebase Authentication. So you can't securely access your Google Cloud SQL database directly from client-side application code. This applies to all supported Cloud SQL databases (MySQL, PostgreSQL, and SQL Server at the moment).